# What causes this syntax error when creating a table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in MySQL, but I am getting an error. The code is looking OK to me, but I don't know why I am getting the error.

This is the code :

```
CREATE TABLE usage (
    user_id    VARCHAR(20) ,
    usage_date  DATE ,
    usage_location     VARCHAR(20) ,
    time_spent      INT
);
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Query 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage (
    user_id    VARCHAR(20) ,
    usage_date  DATE ,
    usage_locatio' at line 1
```

Comment: You should avoid using any of the words on the reserved word list, see: [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U), and only as an escape use the backticks.

Comment: Avoid using RESERVED WORDS and KEYWORDS as identifiers in MySQL. That's still best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting backticks around `usage`. It seems to be a keyword.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `usage` (
    user_id    VARCHAR(20) ,
    usage_date  DATE ,
    usage_location     VARCHAR(20) ,
    time_spent      INT
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using some other names like usage1 for datausage because that is reserved

```
CREATE TABLE stuffusage (
    user_id    VARCHAR(20) ,
    usage_date  DATE ,
    usage_location     VARCHAR(20) ,
    time_spent      INT
);
```

Answer (score 0):

"usage" cannot be used as a table name. It is a special code defined in MYSQL.

Comment: Best practice is to avoid using keywords and reserved words as identifiers in MySQL (table name, column name, etc).  `USAGE` is a MySQL Reserved Word (documented in the MySQL Reference Manual) It is possible to use a reserved word as an identifier, but it has to be properly escaped.  Typically enclosed in backticks,